# Missing error handler on `socket`. TypeError: (msg || "").replace is not a function

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I am getting following error on running unit test in angular2.I am using angular cli as build tool.Karma for unit testing.Any body can suggest a fix for it

Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: (msg || "").replace is not a function
    at D:\AngularjsApp1\src\client\node_modules\karma\lib\reporter.js:45:23
    at onBrowserError (D:\AngularjsApp1\src\client\node_modules\karma\lib\reporters\base.js:58:60)
    at null. (D:\AngularjsApp1\src\client\node_modules\karma\lib\events.js:13:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at onKarmaError (D:\AngularjsApp1\src\client\node_modules\karma\lib\browser.js:95:13)
    at Socket. (D:\AngularjsApp1\src\client\node_modules\karma\lib\events.js:13:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Socket.onevent (D:\AngularjsApp1\src\client\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:335:8)
    at Socket.onpacket (D:\AngularjsApp1\src\client\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:295:12)
    at Client.ondecoded (D:\AngularjsApp1\src\client\node_modules\socket.io\lib\client.js:193:14)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (D:\AngularjsApp1\src\client\node_modules\component-emitter\index.js:134:20)
    at Decoder.add (D:\AngularjsApp1\src\client\node_modules\socket.io-parser\index.js:247:12)
    at Client.ondata (D:\AngularjsApp1\src\client\node_modules\socket.io\lib\client.js:175:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)